# I have tried playing VCDs and DVDs but I always get this type of error: ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the Software Center and installing the proper codecs for playing CDs once you do that, you should be able to play them.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu strives to make all of the most important software available to its users automatically. However patent and copyright restrictions complicate distribution of software to support non-free formats.

You can install the ability to play popular non-free media formats, including DVD, MP3, Quicktime, and Windows Media formats, by installing the `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. Open terminal and type in the following.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras